# parsing xml file with similar tags and different attributes!

Tags: python

I am sorry if this is a repeated question or a basic one as I am new to Python. I am trying to parse the following XML commands so that I can "extract" the tag value for Daniel and George. I want the answer to look like Daniel = 78, George = 90.

```
<epas:property name="Tom">12</epas:property>
<epas:property name="Alice">34</epas:property>
<epas:property name="John">56</epas:property>
<epas:property name="Danial">78</epas:property>
<epas:property name="George">90</epas:property>
<epas:property name="Luise">11</epas:property>
```

The xml commands are stored in one string. i.e. **myString** so here is the first part of code that I tried to parse this string (myString):

```
element = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(myString).getElementByTagName ("epas:property")
if not element:
   print "error message"
else:
    for el in element:
        value [el.getAttribute("name")] = el.firstChild.data
```

I tried to reference Daniel and George to the array index to get the value but looks I am not doing it correctly. I would appreciate your ideas/comments on this.

Cheers, Bill

Comment: Put the XML and Python code in CODE format so it would display correctly.

Comment: Are you getting an error ? 
If you fix .getElementByTagName to .getElementsByTagName and you wrap that xml fragment in a root elem with namespace declared, the rest should work. If not, you should be getting an error message.

Comment: I the XML that you are trying to parse verbatim what is shown in the question? If so, it isn't valid XML. There needs to be a root element to contain the property items. That could be the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use xml.dom.minidom, it's a terrible library!  Use [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) or [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) (ElementTree is in the standard library and will probably work fine for you).

You *should* have an XML namespace, i.e., something like `xmlns:epas="http://something"`.  Also you can't have bare elements, they need to be enclosed.  If you have "fake" namespaces (i.e., no declaration) you could punt and do:

```
myString = '<doc xmlns:epas="dummy">%s</doc>' % myString
```

With ElementTree it's something like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
doc = ET.fromstring(myString)
result = {}
for el in doc.findall('{http://something}property):
    result[el.get('name')] = int(el.text)
```

Comment: Thanks Ian. I have Python 2.5.4 version installed but I am getting: "No Module named etree.ElementTree as ET". As you said ElenetTree is in the standard library so should work with Python 2.5.4! Am I missing something here? :-)

Comment: 2.5 should include ElementTree.  On some operating systems it *might* be a separate installation (i.e., the packager split it out of the standard library).  You can also just install ElementTree then do `import ElementTree as ET`.